# Continoues replication from application postgresql RDS to Reporting RDS using AWS Lamda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am new to Lambda. I have a application PostgresSQL database, data will be inserted into the same.
In another side I have a Reporting PostgresSQL database to store reports. As soon as data inserted into application DB, the Lambda function have to trigger automatically for storing reports into Reports RDS. The help would appriciat.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a solution similar to your problem on AWS blog
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/

It uses Amazon RDS for postgresql and streams data

Comment: Thank you much the above link and let me try this and will get back.